# Customized underline below frame titles

Tags: underline, frame-title

I would like to have frame titles underlined exactly as long as the title runs and hopefully be able to have different colors for the title and the line. For now I have,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left, wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    {\strut\color{blue}\bfseries\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1.5ex%
    \rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.6cm\relax}{0.4pt}}
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
    %
}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}

\begin{itemize}
    \item dd
    \item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Would it be possible to have the underline stop when the frame title stops (so that the line only appears under the words rather than running through the whole slide) and have different colors for the title and the line?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it. The rule length depends on the main title. I show an example on the first slide to include a longer sub title. I assume you won't use subtitle because you didn't mention it in the question. If you wanna the rule length change follow the subtitle you need the change the code accordingly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \settowidth{\@tempdimb}{\bfseries\insertframetitle}%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left, wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    {\strut\color{blue}\bfseries\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1.5ex%
    \color{red}\rule{\@tempdimb}{0.4pt}}
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
    %
}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}{test very long sub title}

\begin{itemize}
    \item dd
    \item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Testing of Longer Frame title}

\begin{itemize}
    \item dd
    \item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]